# How to set up multiple distinct display configurations in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, display-settings, multiple-desktop

To get it out the way: I'm **not** asking how to make a multi-monitor a setup. I already have one.
I need to have a few separate setups which I could switch to and from easily.

My setup consists of:

- 3 monitors in my cave,
- 1 TV in the living room,
- 1 monitor in the bedroom.

All of them are connected directly via HDMI and make up 3 separate "terminals" with their own dedicated mice and keyboards. I want to be able to switch between the terminals easily.

I know the "Win+P" shortcut which gives me: "PC screen only", "Extend" and "Second screen only" ("Duplicate" is useless in this context). When I set the 3 monitors as the "extend" config and the TV as the "second screen only", everything works fine and I can switch between them easily. But as soon as I add the bedroom monitor as "PC screen only" it messes up the "extend" config which no longer consists of the 3 monitors in my cave and now also includes the bedroom monitor (or is even more messed up, I'm not sure at this point)...

Is there a way around this? A way to have more than 2 distinct monitor configurations? Maybe using some separate software?